# Are there any good free file management components for asp .net?

Tags: asp.net, file, document, components

I'm looking for a decent file management control for ASP .Net that I can integrate into an existing website. The requirement is that the user should be able to upload / download documents of various file types as well as edit / delete them.

I've seen the [Telerik FileExplorer](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/fileexplorer/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx) and it looks ideal. However, I would like to determine whether there are any free / open source based alternatives before purchasing this.

Also, if the component has a means to retrieve and store documents from Sharepoint then that would be even better!

Thanks,

Brian.